# how can I add a list of parameters determined by fields to a single "if" generic statement?

Tags: java, refactoring

I'm refactoring a test and its already working alright but I've stumble into the following: I got  list of parameters that represents fields on the screen, for each one there is a "if" condition, if that parameter is called I pass some values to a post method. I wanna make one generic "if" that checks one parameter and goes on to the next and so.

```
    public object = constructor.ifRequired("properties.key.to.field");
public object2 = constructor.ifRequired("properties.key.to.field");
public object3 = constructor.ifRequired("properties.key.to.field");

//post implementation

if(object) {
    post.param = "param1", "param2";
}
if(object2) {
    post.param = "param3", "param4";
}
if(object2) {
    post.param = "param5", "param6";
}
```

I wanna make it work like:

```
//post implementation

if(objectx) {
    post.param = "getParamForObjectx", "getParamForObjectx";
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: This is not valid Java